# Sending Http request to akamai with multiple tokens

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, request, akamai

I am trying to send a simple HTTP request to one of our akamai servers. However I always get the error:

> 400 Authorization Header Missing

I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: 'http://*****************.luna.akamaiapis.net/ccu/v3/invalidate/url/production',
      cache: false,
      headers: {
        client_secret: "****************************",
        host: "************************",
        access_token: "*************************",
        client_token: "***********************"
      },
      data: {
        "username": "my_username",
        "password": "my_password"
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      type: 'get',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "here is my access token");
      }
    });
    
    request.done(function(output) {
      if (output.result == 'success') {
        $("#nachricht").text("success");
      } else {
        $("#nachricht").text("fehler");
      }
    });
    
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      $("#nachricht").text("netzwerk fehler");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to provide the correct header in the request in order to authenticate/authorise your access. If you are providing the header already then you need to ensure that the value you're sending is in the correct format/encoding. As such we cannot answer this - the problem is determined by your security logic, not the code you've provided.

Comment: Ah, I think I got the main problem. For authentification, I need to add akamaiedgegrid some how to my application.